# How can I prove this function is uniformly continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, uniform-continuity

The function is $$ f : B((0,0),1) \rightarrow \Bbb R,\,f(x,y)={xy\over{x-1}}. $$
I tried with sequences: Let be $ \{(x_k,y_k)\} $ and $ \{(x'_k,y'_k)\} $ sequences of $B((0,0),1)$ such that $ \{(x_k-x'_k,y_k-y'_k)\}\rightarrow(0,0). $

So, $ \{f(x_k,y_k)- f(x'_k,y'_k)\}={x_kx'_k(y_k-y'_k)+x'_ky'_k-x_ky_k\over{x_kx'_k-x_k-x'_k+1}} $

I know $x_kx'_k(y_k-y'_k) $ tends to zero but I don't know what to do with $x'_ky'_k-x_ky_k.$

I previously tried with some sequences to find one such that $ \{f(x_k,y_k)- f(x'_k,y'_k)\}$ tends to a non-zero number so that the function is not uniformly continuous  but I didn't find it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider two sequences $(x_n^1,y_n^1)=(1-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{2})$, $(x_n^2,y_n^2)=(1-\frac{1}{2n},\frac{1}{2})$.

Note $\|(x_n^1,y_n^1)-(x_n^2,y_n^2)\|=\frac{1}{2n}\to 0$. But $\|f(x_n^1,y_n^1)-f(x_n^2,y_n^2)\|=\frac{n}{2}\to \infty$.

So it's not uniformly continuous.

Comment: I guess it's difficult to answer but, is there an aproximate technique or method to try to find those kind of counterexample sequences in general only seeing a function f? I tried with 6 or 7 sequences but all of them told me {f(x)-f(x')} -> 0

Comment: @AarónDavidArroyoTorres I don't know the general method. But there are some counterexamples you need to remember first and when you see $f$, you need to compare it with those counterexamples you know and find the similarity. For example, we know $\frac{1}{x},x\in (0,1)$ is not uniformly continuous, the problem appears when $x$ approaches $0$. Hence similarly $\frac{x}{x-1}=1+\frac{1}{x-1},x\in (0,1)$ is not uniformly continuous, the problem appears when $x$ approaches $1$. And for your   $f$, we guess it's not uniformly continuous, and problem may appear when $x$ approaches $1$.